# Example of using crossval function with ar-function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

Can anyone give or redirect to a source where I could see a simple example of the usage of the [`crossval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) function in MATLAB, where the prediction function is either `AR` or `ARX` function?

I cannot find examples from the MATLAB's documentation or the web...

Comment: Can you define what you mean by `AR` and `ARX` neither are defined in the `crossval` documentation? Also there are 3 examples at the bottom of the page linked to by the question, are they insufficient?

Comment: @slayton I think it means that he wants to use the `ar` function in the `predfun` argument in `crossval`.

Comment: @EitanT ahh thanks, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Is this question still open, or did you get your answers [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58730) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58814)?

Comment: @Schorsch Hi =)  Well technically it is still open, but I don't need the answer anymore :) I couldn't get the answer I wanted, but thanx for the links, I think I saw them back then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this question is already answered on the matworks forum:
http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/58730-example-of-using-crossval-function-with-ar-or-arx-function-in-matlab